# Build apk with android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-gradle-plugin

Are build apk with latest android studio with keystore which imported from PKCS12 return different fingerprint?

Comment: read this:http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Answer (score 0):

You can just convert your p12 file to jks.

1) Create an empty JKS store

```
keytool -genkey -alias anyname -keystore certificate.jks
keytool -delete -alias anyname -keystore certificate.jks
```

2) Import certificate.p12 into certificate.jks

```
keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore certificate.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore certificate.jks -deststoretype JKS
```

Also, make sure that your build variant is set to release.

Comment: Thanks for advice i will try that method, previously is when i generate apk with Android Studio use keystore from p12 file that apk contains diferent fingerprint sha1 but when i generate with eclipse apk contains same fingerprint. So yesterday i modify manually unsigned apk with jarsigner and zipalign to create release apk

is that my method to create keystore are wrong or problem at android studio (i use android studio 2.1 preview)